# Match any ethernet interface with systemd.networkd

Tags: network-interface, systemd-networkd

How can I match any local ethernet interface within a [`systemd.networkd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#[Match]%20Section%20Options) configuration?
I want it to match all ethernet interfaces, but not wifi interfaces or tunnel interfaces etc. on the local host regardless of their name, driver or MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now got it to work with

```
[Match]
Name=en*
```

as described in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#Basic_DHCP_network).